# Unable to load DLL 'MFCapturer': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) in TokBox

Tags: windows-10, opentok, tokbox

I am making a video sharing tool with the help of TokBox.

This works fine in the Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1
But Same program is giving the 
Unable to load DLL 'MFCapturer': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) error in the Windows 10.

Is there any way to fix it.

Comment: Why the downvote? Same problem here, reported to Tokbox support.

Comment: Do you compile 32-bit, 64-bit or AnyCPU ? Is the target OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64 bit for Windows 10 Pro N

Comment: Have you tried what I write in my answer (below this comment thread), that is, install "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015"? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation [OpenTok Windows SDK - for building WebRTC video apps on Windows](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/windows/) states:

> When creating an installer for your application, add Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 as an installer package. Use the x86 version, the x64 version, or both, depending on the architecture of your application.

We installed 64-bit version because everything was 64-bit, had same problem as you and reported to vendor.

We observed that even with platform-agnostic .NET code, running on a 64-bit OS required installing 32-bit version of the C++ redistributable on the target.

Edit: download link for both versions https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840

Comment: This fixed it for me! Guess I should've read their docs better.